# How to remove a user from a group?

Tags: users

I added a user account to the `admin` group and discovered I added wrong user. So I now have to remove the account from the `admin` group.

How can I remove an account from a group without deleting the user?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Portablejim's answer is accurate but dangerous -- if you typo something, your system may be unusable, *especially* if you alter the admin group improperly.  If you must edit the groups file, use the `vipw -g` or `vigr` commands, which verify the syntax before saving.  Even then, there are better ways.

From a commandline, the one you probably want to use is the following (as root):

```
deluser <username> <groupname>
```

This will remove the specified user from the specified group. You must relogin to see the effect. It will not delete the user, or the group, just the membership.  There are also ways of doing it with the `usermod` command, but it's harder to use as you need to replace the entire list of groups for a user in order to remove a single group.  The `gpasswd` command is also capable of doing this (as sagarchalise points out), but is mostly deprecated. As always, see the man pages for more details.

Comment: `gpasswd` is not deprecated. Its entire purpose is to administer /etc/group and /etc/gshadow. Also, while your method does work, and is mentioned in the deluser man page, it's a bit risky. If you accidentally hit enter before you type the group name, you've remove the user. Better hope you remember its UID so you can add it back quickly. It would be safer to use gpasswd which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: I thought about this risk too. I guess you can always start such a command with a '#', hit enter, and then rerun it while just removing the first character.

Comment: "You must relogin to see the effect." ...or you could just write: 'cat /etc/group'

Comment: I had found `deluser` while searching man pages (here with Ubuntu 18 in 2018), but the first line in the man page states: "remove a user or group from the system", so I moved on in my search. Clearly the man page needs to be worded better.

Comment: I found this answer in an article and immediately the hairs on the back of my neck stood up. I dont know why so many people like and accept this answer, but it's dangerous IMHO; esp as root. Anthony Geoghegan answer is the proper solution; just as Starfish says as well.

Comment: I really dislike this answer, starting with "Portablejim's answer is accurate but dangerous" and then stating `deluser` as solution where missing the second parameter will immediately delete the user. The "gpasswd" answer is way better in my optinion.

Answer (score 79):

You can do this:

```
sudo gpasswd -d username group
```

See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/gpasswd.1.html

> `-d, --delete user`
> Remove the user from the named group.

Comment: One advantage of `gpasswd` is that it's more cross-platform and also works on Red Hat-based distributions.

Comment: This is the right answer. If only it rose to the top.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain what the -d flag does? (I've voted for it as the best answer, anyway! Thank you!)

Comment: Incorrectly getting `gpasswd: user 'me' is not a member of 'me_group'`

Answer (score 1):

See zanfur's answer.

Edit the `/etc/group` file as root (i.e. `gksudo gedit /etc/group`) and remove the username from the line that starts with 'admin'

i.e.

```
...
admin:x:120:adminuser,adminuser2,userthatshouldnotbeadmin
...
```

becomes

```
...
admin:x:120:adminuser,adminuser2
...
```

Be warned, typos within the file could break your system.

Comment: Please don't advice to edit these system files manually. In case you screw up your system might become inaccessible.

Comment: Or at least back them up first. ([Related information.](http://askubuntu.com/a/147636/22949))

Comment: I think you should post this as it is valuable insight into how Linux works.  However, should include a warning that there is a much safer way

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and safest way:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/group
```

and delete it manually.

Comment: I see this one enrty. `ssh:x:118:`  What is the meaning of the number `118` here ?

Comment: definitely NOT the safest way!

Comment: this worked fo rme, I removed the user from the group and I was good to go.