# I deleted the "/etc/passwd" file and cannot log in

Tags: login, authentication, users, passwd-file

I was trying to change my username and also my home directory (`/home/username`) and my system started to crash. I deleted the `passwd` file but I had a backup named `passwd_bkp`. I tried to rename this `passwd_bkp` as `passwd` and it did not work. No commands were being executed... I was in a terminal window.

I restarted my system and now I cannot log in. GRUB gives two options: Linux and recovery mode.

I tried to open a sessions as root but it says the filesystem is corrupted. I *cannot* access my files.

Did I lose all my files?

Comment: To your follow-up question: Replace your password, using recovery technique. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password

Comment: @david6 When a user cannot login *because there is no `/etc/passwd` file*, it is also not possible to reset the password. You have to restore (or recreate) the `passwd` file. And once that's done, generally there is no need to reset the password.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan:  Agreed, but I was answering the follow-up question, after **/etc/passwd** was (supposedly) restored from backup copy.

Comment: You will need to be more specific about the error.

Answer (score 33):

No, given your description, you did not lose any of your files (except `/etc/passwd`, which you deleted, but which you had backed up).

Boot an Ubuntu live CD/DVD or live USB flash drive. Select `Try Ubuntu` (not `Install Ubuntu`). When the desktop loads, open a Nautilus (file browser) window. You can find the partition for your Ubuntu system under `Devices`. Click on it to mount it.

Now you can restore the backup. You have to do it as root, however. Here's one pretty easy way to do it.

1. Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). In the Terminal, type `cd` and type the <kbd>Space</kbd> key, but don't press <kbd>Enter</kbd> yet.
2. In Nautilus, find the `etc` directory inside the installed Ubuntu system. (This is not the same as the `etc` directory for the live CD. The `etc` directory inside the installed Ubuntu system is in the partition you just mounted.)
3. Drag this `etc` directory into the Terminal, which will paste its full path into the Terminal, completing the `cd ...` command.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command. Now you're in the directory that contained your `passwd` file. I am assuming that your backup file, `passwd_bkp`, is also located here.
5. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo cp passwd_bkp passwd
   ```

That restores the `passwd` file from your backup, so now you should be able to reboot, remove the CD/DVD or USB flash drive, and boot back into your installed Ubuntu system. Your installed Ubuntu system should work again.

---

For the future, you should be aware that it is not recommended to manually edit `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`, `/etc/shadow`, or `/etc/gshadow`. Instead, you should use the utilities provided as part of Ubuntu to make any changes you need to users and groups on your system. You're probably aware that you can edit this in System Settings or with `users-admin`. But there are also very powerful command-line utilities for this, which are still much safer and easier than manually editing the configuration files yourself. Here's documentation on the most relevant such utilities in Ubuntu:

- [`adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/adduser.8.html) / [`addgroup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/addgroup.8.html)
- [`deluser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/deluser.8.html) / [`delgroup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/delgroup.8.html)
- [`usermod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/usermod.8.html)
- [`groupmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/groupmod.8.html)
- [`useradd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/useradd.8.html) (lower-level than `adduser`, you should usually use `adduser` instead)
- [`userdel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/userdel.8.html) (lower-level than `deluser`, you should usually use `deluser` instead)
- [`groupadd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/groupadd.8.html) (lower-level than `addgroup`, you should usually use `addgroup` instead)
- [`groupdel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/groupdel.8.html) (lower-level than `delgroup`, you should usually use `delgroup` instead)
- [`passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/passwd.1.html)
- [`gpasswd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gpasswd.1.html)
- [`pwck`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/pwck.8.html)
- [`grpck`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/grpck.8.html)

You can [change your username](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username) with some of those utilities. [This answer explains one way in detail.](https://askubuntu.com/a/34075/22949) However, you should be aware (as is currently touched on by a comment there) that some applications assume your username remains the same. So changing your username might cause some problems.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is four o' clock in the morning here in south Brazil...I was so woried that I could not sleep. I will try that...

Comment: If you did not make a backup, try using `/etc/passwd-` or `/var/backups/passwd.bak`. Be sure to set the correct permissions. Example: `sudo install -m644 /etc/passwd- /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to booting a livecd, you could press `e` at the grub menu to edit the rescue mode entry, and add `init=/bin/sh` to the kernel arguments.  This will drop you right to a root shell where you can copy the backup file back to the original after remounting the filesystem read-write with `mount -o remount,rw /`.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Without `/etc/passwd`, *there is no user called root, and no user with uid=0*. Will the needed utilities necessarily work under those unusual conditions?

Comment: @EliahKagan, there is *always* a user with uid=0 since that is the uid that the kernel starts the first process out with.  `cp` or `mv` don't need /etc/passwd.

Comment: this saved my dumb butt! i manual edit on /etc/shadow regarding crontab stuff. I did not know one does not mess with 'shadow'.... 
I thought that i was f**ckd but thank god for @psusi.... I edited the grub menu for recovery added /bin/sh as he said , followed his mount and just copied shawdow from /var/backups over the corrupt one in /etc... Good as new.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should read first Eliah Kagan's answer, before continuing reading this answer. He explains how to deal with the situation and why it is usually not necessary to change /etc/passwd manually.

Anyhow if you **really know what you are doing** and you **need to edit `/etc/passwd` manually**, you can do it, but still you should not simply change the files with your favourite editor. Instead there is the tool

```
vipw
```

From the man pages:

```
The vipw and vigr commands edits the files /etc/passwd and /etc/group,
respectively. With the -s flag, they will edit the shadow versions of those
files, /etc/shadow and /etc/gshadow, respectively. The programs will set
the appropriate locks to prevent file corruption.
```

For e.g. if you want to change a users UID, as far as I know, to edit the files manually, is the only way. Also if you want to change a users password and then back to its previous without knowing it, there is no way with `usermod` or so. But if you save the hashed password form the shadow file, then change the user's password you can afterwards add the hashed password again editing the shadow file with `vipw -s`.

Answer (score 1):

After following @EliahKagan's answer I could not login from `lightdm` and my account wasn't listed. I discovered that the permission of the `passwd` file was not set up properly; the lightdm user did not have access to it. Here's how I fixed it:.

Log in on a tty <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

change to the `/etc` directory

```
cd /etc
```

Then change the permissions to `644`

```
sudo chmod 644 passwd
```

Then do `ls -la`

the permission string should look like this

```
-rw-r--r--
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can login just open terminal and try this :

```
sudo cp /etc/passwd- /etc/passwd
sudo chmod 644 /etc/passwd
```

Else

Boot  into recovery mode  or from Ubuntu live Cd . Then, mount your old drive:

```
mkdir /olddrive
mount /dev/hda5 /olddrive
assuming that your old drive is on /dev/hda5.
then, cd to /olddrive/etc
type:
echo "root::0:0:Superuser:/:/bin/bash" > passwd
```

then reboot. That will set no passwd for root.

Then, you can login, create all of your accounts over again, etc.

You may also use the back up which is called (I think) `/etc/passwd-`

**Edit**:(another method I haven't tried before but I think it should work also)

- Start GRUB on boot (press <kbd>Esc</kbd> while booting)
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> over (recovery mode)
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> over the line beginning with kernel
- Press <kbd>Space</kbd> and enter `init=/bin/bash`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press <kbd>b</kbd>
- At command prompt type: `cp /etc/passwd- /etc/passwd`
- Reboot to GRUB again
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> over (recovery mode)
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> over the line beginning with kernel
- Press <kbd>Space</kbd> and enter `init=/bin/bash`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press <kbd>b</kbd>
- At command prompt type `mount -o remount,rw /`
- Type `passwd YOURUSERNAMEHERE` (If you don't know your username type `ls /home` (that is a Lower case L and lower case S) for a list of users)
- Enter new password at prompt
- Reboot to normal boot.

[Source](https://admin-ahead.com/forum/general-linux/recovery-of-deleted-etcpasswd-file-in-linux/)