# Remove a users right to use sudo

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

As an administrator, how can remove a users rights to use SUDO. Is there a simple command to do this?

Comment: hey PerlDuck, please what is the exact command to do that?

Answer (score 11):

Only users in the `sudo` group may use the `sudo` command. To remove the user `jdoe` from the group `sudo` type (as `root`):

```
deluser jdoe sudo
```

If you are not `root`, type

```
sudo deluser jdoe sudo
```

Reference: [How to remove a user from a group?](https://askubuntu.com/q/80115/504066)

---

#### Update

As pointed out by [@Aleks G](https://askubuntu.com/users/103954/aleks-g) in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009367/remove-a-users-right-to-use-sudo/1009368?noredirect=1#comment1635092_1009368) the above is only half the truth:

By default only members of the `sudo` group may run commands with `sudo <command>`. This is accomplished by the line

```
#  who  where    as-whom  what
  %sudo  ALL  = (ALL:ALL) ALL
```

in the `/etc/sudoers` file. It means:

- members of the group `sudo` (*who*) may run
- on any computer (*where*)
- as any user and any group (*as-whom*)
- any command (*what*)

This is the default setup on Ubuntu and hence adding or removing a user to/from the group `sudo` gives or revokes the privilege to run commands with `sudo <command>`.

**But** it is also possible to add other groups and/or users to the `/etc/sudoers` file (or below `/etc/sudoers.d/`) like so:

```
alice  myhost  = (bob) /bin/ls
```

This means: user `alice` may run `/bin/ls` as user `bob` but only on host `myhost`.

`alice` could now do `sudo -u bob ls /home/bob`. This is independant of a membership in the `sudo` group. If you have such a setup, then it is *not* sufficient to remove `alice` from the `sudo` group. Instead you need to remove the `alice` line from the `/etc/sudoers` file.

The *where* part is only relevant if you share the `sudoers` file across different computers and want to keep it the same on every computer.

Comment: This answer is factually wrong.  Any user can be granted sudo rights by their username directly - for example with the following line in the sudoers file: `username   ALL=(ALL)   ALL` or via any other group using `%somegroup ALL=(ALL) ALL`

Comment: @AleksG Yes. Of course you are right. I don't know what made me forget that yesterday. I updated my answer to include this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

The answer regarding the sudo group is correct for *most* situations.  There is another way to give a user sudo rights, and that is to add their username directly to the sudoers file.  If the username has been added, then it must be removed from that file -- Usually the entire line containing the username.  This is not a common scenario, but is possible.  To edit the sudoers file, use visudo.